# Python-docx: How to add StringIO image to a docx file?

Tags: python, python-docx

I can use this code to insert  an image into docx file

```
from docx import Document

document = Document()
p = document.add_paragraph()
r = p.add_run()
r.add_picture('/tmp/foo.jpg')
```

But if I have  the image as a StringIO object. How can I do it without saving it as a file?

P:S: Library I'm using is python-docx

Comment: Can you please link to the library you're using?

Comment: An image is supposed to be a binary object. You should use `BytesIO` instead of `StringIO`.

Comment: I'm using  python-docx library

Comment: I am using python 2.7. So I had to use StringIO

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let us have a quick read of the [python-docx documentation](https://python-docx.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api/document.html#docx.document.Document.add_picture).

> add_picture(image_path_or_stream, width=None, height=None)

So, you should be to pass the stream directly to this function.

```
image = BytesIO()
r.add_picture(image)
```

Comment: I am getting `docx.image.exceptions.UnrecognizedImageError` what can i do?

Comment: Sounds like you need to convert your image to a supported format first. [PIL](https://pillow.readthedocs.io/en/stable/) or similar will probably be of use to you.

Comment: But how do I convert an image to blob format? Or do I have to convert it before uploading it to the database?

Comment: There's no such thing as a "blob format". A blob is merely a datatype (generally in a database) which stores raw binary data. Further discussion on this probably merits another question.